# customKeyIdentifier of 32 bytes that converted to hexadecimal thumbprint do not match Azure Portal thumbprint

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-service-principal

Collecting data using MS Graph cmdlet **Get-MgServicePrincipal**.
Under `keyCredentials` (also the same are available under `passwordCredentials`) i can see all the self-signed certificates created either from portal or trough powershell, but the problem is when using bitConverter the 32 byte `customKeyIdentifier` ones, as expected do not match the 20 byte (40 hexadecimals) that are shown in the portal.
Also as side effect i cannot define which is the active one, stored under the `preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint` property - which is 40 hexadecimal thumbprint of a certificate that under `keyCredentials` in some cases is 64 hexadecimal thumbprint.

Viewed from portal everything is fine.

I have tried to collect data using direct api calls and converting the base64 string with the same result.

Comment: The issue can be during conversion. Could you please share the code how do you convert bytes?

Comment: `[System.BitConverter]::ToString($spn.keyCredentials.CustomKeyIdentifier).Replace('-','')`
The issue is not from the conversion, the byte array is either 32 (when portal created cert) or 20 (created with powershell cmdlet)